# how to save redirection url to csv file in python

Tags: python, file, redirect, csv, save

i have a redirection url

www.test.com

it will redirect me to

www.test.com/XXYYXXYY

ans every time when i open it will redirect me to a new url ( XXYYXXYY will change every time )

so i want to save them into a CSV file

```
import urllib2
import csv
import sys

url = 'http://www.test.com'

u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
localFile = open('file.csv', 'w')
localFile.write(u.read())
localFile.close()
```

is this a correct code ?

thank you

Comment: What are you trying to save? The contents of the site or the unique URL? What happens when you run the code?  Does it work the way you expect it? If so, then it's (more or less) correct. I would just change to `with open('file.csv', 'w') as localFile:`

Comment: brandon ( every final url will give me a unique code so i want to save the url then i can save the part of the code for example: www.test.com will redirect to www.test.com/XXXXYYYY i want to save the final url then i can delete the ( www.test.com ) to get just the code ( XXXXYYYY )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

geturl() will give you the final URL

```
import urllib2
import csv
import sys

url = 'http://www.test.com'

u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
localFile = open('file.csv', 'w')
localFile.write(u.geturl())
localFile.close()
```

Comment: ton1c thank you so much i tried your code but nothing happened! ( there is no csv file ! ) see my code below

import urllib2
import csv
import sys

url = 'http://www.test.com'

u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
localFile = open('C:\test\file.csv', 'w')
localFile.write(u.geturl())
localFile.close()

and why it won't work ?

sorry i'm beginner

Comment: Your location of the file is wrong. To create file use this `C:\\test\\file.csv` as file location. To create CSV correctl use CSV library: `writer = csv.writer(localfile) writer.writerow(u.geturl())`

Comment: thank you so much it's working now !!
but there are 2 problems
1-every letter or number takes 1 cell ( i want the whole url in 1 cell )
2-if i run the script 2 times it will delete the first url and save the new one ( i want to save all the urls and every url takes 1 cell )

Comment: hi ton1c i finally know how to put the whole url into 1 cell by this code writer.writerow([u.geturl()])  but the second problem i don't know how to solve it ( i mean how to save the urls instead of removing the old url and replace it with a new url )

Comment: Hi, use [append to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-file-in-python). So instead of `localFile = open('file.csv', 'w')` use `localFile = open('file.csv', 'a')`

Comment: thank you ton1c for helping me
and i have another problem ( the script write codes in 1 column for example A1 then A3 then A5 ) how to make it write the codes by rows for example A1 B1 C1 D1  please see this to explain it more http://i.imgur.com/Gl5jdrf.jpg  the red color that what i want instead of blue color

Comment: You should have opened it as a new question, but to fix it open file in binary - `open('file.csv', 'ab')`

Comment: hi ton1c
i opened a new question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564390/python-csv-list-by-rows-instead-of-columns